# Why isn't my click event working on a second click of a button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a page with a variable number of modals.  When a modal is shown I add a click event to the button on the modal.  When I click the button the event is fired and the next modal is shown.  However, on the second modal, nothing is fired when I click the button.

Any thoughts as to why the event listener wouldn't fire on a second click.
This is the code to add the event listener to each modal.  `onSubmission` is the function that does some ajax stuff and hides the current modal, then shows the next modal.

```
function addSubmitAction(formId) {
    console.log(formId);
    document.querySelector('#modal-submit').addEventListener('click', function _listener() {
        onSubmission({ 'id': formId });
        document.querySelector('#modal-submit').removeEventListener('click', _listener, true);
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: Is the second modal inserted dynamically? Then you need to bind the event again (after inserting it)

Comment: Do all your modals have the same `id`?

Comment: It looks like you are removing the event listener before you get a chance to click the next modal button.  Do you even need to remove the listener?

Comment: Add `console.log(document.querySelector('#modal-submit'))` after `console.log(formId)` and i think you'll see old modal button that doesn't exist.

Comment: The second modal is really just the same modal, just with different data.  The modals have different ids.   Because a different id needed, I need to add a new listener, or at least need a way to get the id to the onSubmission function.  I can use jQuery, but am trying to avoid it (mostly just 'cause).

Comment: @AlexanderAnikeev, you're kind of right.  Turns out, I'm not really getting rid of the modal when I hide it, and I'm also not just re-using the modal framework like I thought.  I'm just hiding the first modal, and adding in a second modal on-top of the first modal.

Comment: @spuppett If they all have unique `ids` then that gets rid of one possible problem with what you have presented here, I am unsure of why you can't just add all the click events once the page has loaded, pass in the id of the clicked modal and then map which modal should open next and hide the current one and show the next one. It might help if we had a little more to go on with your code.

Comment: @spuppett try to use cascade selector from formId `#form1 .modal-submit`.

Comment: @RyanWilson That's a good idea, I'll run with it.  I only posted the code that I thought might be wrong with why the event listener wasn't working.  Thanks.

Comment: @spuppett Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

may be u need get click event on root node?

```
        document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
          if( target.id !== submitId ) return;
          /// your logic
        });
```

[example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gQfFYcMTsp5BaMDV24Nr?p=preview)